# Pgadmin connectivity issue with application server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am using pgadmin 4.2.0 but when I open it to use, it shows the following error

```
The application server could not be contacted.
```

I installed and uninstalled the Postgres and pgadmin using brew many times but facing the same issue.

Thanks in advance,

Aisha Zafar

Comment: On which OS do you face this issue?

Comment: I am using MacOS

Comment: Was the docker image helpful to you?

Comment: I was using pgadmin 4.2.0 and the latest version is 4.2.1. As the version is not stable yet thats why I never wanted to install it but now due to this problem I installed 4.2.1 and its working.

Comment: Thanks for your help@Jakob

Comment: Can you reset your %PYTHONPATH%  environment variable and try again?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be the usage of this docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/fenglc/pgadmin4/

Answer (score 0):

you can fix that problem with the following terminal command:

```
mv $HOME/.pgadmin $HOME/.pgadmin_backup
```

The problem is caused by the contents of the folder "~/.pgadmin". This folder may contain corrupt files or files of an incompatible pgadmin version. The above command renames the folder so that there are no more annoying, old data. If necessary, old configurations can be reconstructed from the old folder.